# WinHttpSendRequest and ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST

Tags: c, winapi, winhttp, getlasterror

Is it possible for GetLastError() to return ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST after calling WinHttpSendRequest?

Documentation for WinHttpSendRequest:

> ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST 
>   The application must call
>   WinHttpSendRequest again due to a redirect or authentication
>   challenge. Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows XP with SP2 and
>   Windows 2000:  This error is not supported.

But samples from MSDN (Authentication in WinHTTP) checks for this value after WinHttpReceiveResponse.

Comment: You are propably referring to the example at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx). Look again at the code. The check for `ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST` is done if either `WinHttpSendRequest()` or `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But samples from MSDN (Authentication in WinHTTP) checks for this
>   value after WinHttpReceiveResponse.

At a first glance [the sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx) may look like that. But if you look closely, the sample actually checks for `ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST` if **either** `WinHttpSendRequest()` **or** `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` fails:

```
// Send a request.
bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                               WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                               0,
                               WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                               0, 
                               0, 
                               0 );

// End the request.
if( bResults )
  bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

// Resend the request in case of 
// ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST error.
if( !bResults && GetLastError( ) == ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST)
    continue;
```

If `WinHttpSendRequest()` returns `FALSE`, the call to `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` will be skipped and `GetLastError()` will be checked for `ERROR_WINHTTP_RESEND_REQUEST`. This code is inside a `while` loop, so the `continue` statement will cause the remaining portion of the loop to be skipped so `WinHttpSendRequest()` will be called again.

**Conclusion:** The sample is in line with the reference documentation.